# Prove that $p(x) = \alpha (x)f(x) + \beta (x)g(x)$ for some irreducible $f(x)$, $g(x)$.

Tags: field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be irreducible polynomials of different degrees in field $F[x]$. Prove that for all $p(x) \in F[x]$ that there exists some $\alpha(x), \beta(x)\in F[x]$ such that $p(x) = \alpha (x)f(x) + \beta (x)g(x).$

I think I have a legitimate proof for this, however I would like to check my thinking.

First, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are irreducible and have different degrees, then they are the polynomial equivalent to relatively prime numbers and therefore have a GCD of 1. I did use my definition about irreducible polynomials from the text, but just want to soldify thinking with something I'm already comfortable with.

Second, since the above GCD = 1, then we can say that $1 = a(x)f(x)+b(x)g(x)$.

Can I then multiply both sides of the equation by $p(x)$ to result in $p(x) = p(x)a(x)f(x) + p(x)b(x)g(x)$?

Does that then allow me to say that as long as we define $\alpha (x) = p(x)a(x)$ and $\beta(x) = p(x)g(x)$ and we know that $F$ is a field so is multiplicatively closed, then $\alpha(x), \beta(x) \in F$, that $p(x)=\alpha(x)f(x)+\beta(x)g(x)$?

Comment: I think you mean for every polynomial $p(x)$ there exist $\alpha(x)$ and $\beta(x)$ such that...

Comment: The quantifiers in your statement aren't what you intend.  What you mean to say, I believe, is that, given $p(x)\in F[x]$ there exist $\alpha(x),\beta (x)\in F[x]$ which satisfy the equation you write.  That statement is what you (correctly) argue, starting from the result that you can solve the problem for $p(x)=1$.

Comment: I corrected the original problem. Sorry, in an effort to shorten the statement I changed the meaning a little.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are irreducible over the field $F$ and neither is a scalar multiple of the other their gcd is $1$, and then since $F[x]$ is a [principal ideal domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal_domain) you have [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity).  In fact you just need  $p(x)$ to be irreducible and not to divide $q(x)$ (or the same with $p$ and $q$ interchanged).